# Matching multiple domains in an XPath expression

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

At the moment I'm doing something like this to get all links pointing to a certain domain from the page:

```
var links = entryNode.SelectNodes(".//a[contains(@href,'site.com')]");
```

I would like to modify this so I can get `a` elements that point to any domain that I specify. For example:

```
var links = entryNode.SelectNodes(".//a[contains(@href,'site.com') | contains(@href,'othersitesite.com') | contains(@href,'thirdsite.com')]");
```

Is there a way to do this in one XPath expression?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
.//a[contains(@href,'site.com')
   or
     contains(@href,'othersitesite.com')
   or
     contains(@href, 'thirdsite.com')
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the requirement that you want to *entirely* match the portion of the string occurring after the `//` and before any subsequent `/` (i.e. you want to match subdomains too), then the following solution works:

```
.//a[contains(' site.com othersitesite.com thirdsite.com ', 
             concat(' ', substring-before(substring-after(
                                          concat(@href, '/'), '//'), '/'), ' '))]
```

This works because you're looking for the target string surrounded by spaces in a larger string that contains all of the possible target strings each surrounded by spaces.

Let's use a concrete example. Assume you have the following document:

```
<r>
    <a href="http://google.com"/>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com/"/>
    <a href="http://bing.com"/>
    <a href="http://altavista.com"/>
</r>
```

And you want to match anchors for *google.com*, *yahoo.com*, and *altavista.com* (relative to the current node). The following expression accomplishes that:

```
.//a[contains(' google.com yahoo.com altavista.com ', 
             concat(' ', substring-before(substring-after(
                                          concat(@href, '/'), '//'), '/'), ' '))]
```

You might not have the requirement stated above. If that's the case, then just use @Dimitre's (good) answer. This solution is merely presented as a possible alternative that might also help you further understand your own requirements.